# Laravel Eloquent - __call() function to get query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way for me to get the `$query` in the `__call($name, $argument)` magic function? Just like when you say `scopeColumn($query, $value)`, is there a way I get the `$query?`

Comment: You want to override `__call` method on you model?

Comment: yes, i do, so that if I say for example `whereColumn(value)` it will automatically invoke `$query->where('column', '=', value)`

Comment: It works that way, there is dynamic `where` feature.

Comment: For some reason, mine doesn't work. I thought from the documentation that it should. Actually `whereId($id)` works. I also have a column called `day` that takes an integer, but calling `whereDay($day)` returns an error that says `missing argument 2 for Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::whereDay()`

Comment: The error says everything. You need at least 3 parameters for that method (which is a method on the Query Builder since 4.1.25, along with `whereMonth` & `whereYear` working as SQL: `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()`). So, obviously, you can't use dynamic calls for this very method name.

Comment: ohhhhh Thanks alot!! This answers a lot!! If you put your comment as an answer I can vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic `where` works as expected.

But `whereDay`, `whereMonth` and `whereYear` are defined methods on the Query Builder since 4.1.25 working for `SQL: DAY(), MONTH(), YEAR())`.

So, obviously, you can't use dynamic calls for `whereDay`.